# Current sense op-amp with integrated shunt vs expensive resistor

Tags: operational-amplifier, current-measurement, shunt, current-sensing

To simplify my question lets assume:

I need to convert +/-7.07A RMS AC current into +/-707mV RMS voltage with high acurracy (0.1% or better).

It may be also higher voltage, up to +/-2.5Vpk.

---

For now I just measure voltage on Ohmite 15FR100E resistor:

- 100mOhm
- 90PPM/°C
- 35°C/W
- 5W

**When I'm trying to measure 5A RMS current It probably heats up by about 87.5°C (calculated from thermal resistance and power) and that gives about 0.788% resistance change (calculated: 87.5°C * 90PPM/°C).**

---

I want to improve this and I'm thinking about two options:

**OPTION 1.** Use expensive resistor: Powertron FPR 4-T221 0R100 S 1% Q

- 100mOhm
- 25PPM/°C
- 4.8°C/W
- 3°C/W heatsink
- 15W
- 4-terminal

**And this should give me 0.024% resistance change (from 5A RMS).**

---

**OPTION 2.** Use [INA250](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina250.pdf?ts=1590445578210) current sense amplifier with fixed gain and integrated 2mOhm shunt.

INA250 op amp features from datasheet:

[image]

I think, that I can assume

- I can forgot about thermal problems because shunt R is very small
- I can compensate 0.3% gain error
- If I pick 200mV/A version - I'll get 2x higher voltage vs my shunt and this is fine

But I'm not sure about (QUESTIONS):

- Can I just ignore 50mA offset error (this is ~0,7% of my 7.07A peak current) when I need to measure sine RMS acurrately?
- should I expect some extra sources of errors when I replace shunt with INA250?
- is this that simple? really? $4 op-amp replaces big expensive shunt just like that?

Attachments:

Cheap Ohmite resistor which I'm using now:

[image]

Expensive Powertron resistor:

[image]

---

If someone asks why I'm not using resistor like 10mOhm to reduce heat - the answer is because I tried to avoid 10x gain op-amp in circuit, that would be extra source of errors. Maybe I was wrong. Actually this is not about measurements, I'm building current source similar to this:

http://www.kswichit.com/VCCS/vccs.htm

Comment: "...with high acurracy (**0.1% or better**)." - why?

Comment: Because this circuit is supposed to be used as calibrator for some product (measurement device) which is capable to archive 0.1% acurracy. With 0.1% acurracy calibrator I will be able to reach about 0.2% product acurracy. This is good enough for product purpose, but if it is possible to get 0.05% calibrator for few bucks (lke 20-50USD) more - why not. And maybe I will be able to measure smaller currents more accurately on single range (one resistor) instead of making range switch.

Answer (score 1):

If you want o build a calibration tool, you tool should be more accurate than the product you are attempting to calibrate.
You seem to be making a meal out of sensing with relatively high value series sensing resistors. You should be trying to minimize the sense R.

You could start [here](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/01332B.pdf) or [here](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/an105fa.pdf) for pointers on how to measure accurately (ignore the fact that the links are about measuring low currents). These will give you a much better understanding of the accuracy and performance you might achieve.

One great article to ponder is [this](https://www.eevblog.com/projects/ucurrentoriginal/), on the uCurrent Gold. 
[image]
The basic design could scale to many amps with ease, and with high accuracy and very low burden power dissipation.

Comment: "You should be trying to minimize the sense R."
I'm worried about noises and offsets from op-amp input at low voltages/resistances. I shouldn't? How low can I go?

Comment: Well, I know a bit about uCurrent and I have parts to build it, but I'm not sure if I can just put MAX4239 with 10-20x gain inside feedback loop of OPA541.

Comment: Low sense R means low noise....obviously. If the 'noise' you describe is in the external current path then it is not 'noise' Tha amplifier is already a low noise part, so noise from the amp should not be a concern.

Comment: I'm more concerned about noise and offset of signal source that feeds OPA. If there is 1mV of noise from signal source - half resistance will double noise to signal ratio. My first prototype has no signal source and I'm using Analog Discovery 2 generator and it looks like there is more than 1mV RMS of noise. This is not a big deal if I'm generating few amps, but when I need pretty 50mA RMS sinewave - noise and offset are huge relatively to signal. Thats why I picked 100mOhm resistor (circuit operates on higher input voltages).